# How to show current week?

Tags: android, eclipse, date

I'm trying to program an android app that show's the current week_of_the_year but haven't found anything similar to what I want, I've seen the date picker but that doesn't show the week numbers and I've also been on android developer site.

So is there any way to view the current week_of_the_year in a really simple way?
If there's anyone who can show me this I'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);`

This should give you the current week in the current time zone.  If you need it for a specific date, there are alternate constructors for GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Hi Sashi, thank you for your comment!

I've just started programming in JAVA, and the examples of datepickers are at least 50 lines long.

So I would put that in my .java file, but how do I make for an example textField to print the week? Thank you!

Comment: @Martin
In the getView method of your adapter,


`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  int weekOfYear = new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
  // viewlayout defined in your layout directory as viewlayout.xml
  View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlayout, parent, false);
  TextView week = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.week);
  week.setText(String.valueOf(weekOfYear));
}`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this on Android is probably to use the [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class:

```
int currentWeek = new Time().getWeekNumber();
```

Comment: This displays 52 the max, how do i get the current?

Comment: `Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
time.getWeekNumber();
`

should do the trick